Ensure type is always inferred from function parameters, even when other type arguments are specified
I want the return type of a function to be a conditional type, based on the value of the function argument. Here is a minimal reproduction:
type R<K extends string> = K extends "test" ? "is test!" : "is not test...";

function D<T, K extends string = string>(v: K): R<K> {
  // Type T would be used for something else
  // This type cast is just for illustrative purposes
  return v as unknown as R<K>;
}

const x = D("test"); // x has type "is test!"
const y = D<string>("test"); // y has type "is not test..."

TS Playground
The type of x is, as expected, "is test!", but the type of y is "is not test...".
It seems to me like specifying the type T causes TypeScript to generalise the type K into the generic string, instead of inferring it based on the value of v. How can I ensure that K is always inferred from v?

TS doesn't have partial type argument inference. The default for K doesn't do anything for you either. See this playground link for a currying workaround, and the linked q/a above for more info.
